# Regex in Objective-C: how to replace matches with a dynamic template?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

My input is like `"Hi {{username}}"`, ie. a string with keywords to replace. However, **the input is quite small** (~ 10 keywords and 1000 characters total), and I have **a million possible keywords** stored in a hashtable data structure, each associated to its replacement.

Therefore, I do not want to iterate over the keyword list and try to replace each one in the input for obvious performance reason. I prefer to iterate only once over the input characters by looking for the regex pattern `"\{\{.+?\}\}"`.

In Java, I make use of the `Matcher.appendReplacement` and `Matcher.appendTail` methods to do that. But I cannot find a similar API with `NSRegularExpression`.

```
private String replaceKeywords(String input)
{        
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.+?)\\}\\}").matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find())
    {
        String replacement = getReplacement(m.group(1));
        m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    }

    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Am I forced to implement such API myself, or did I miss something?

Comment: Why not use a direct replacement function with `HashVar[$1]` or use some kind of callback to verify existence of hash key (i.e. $1). Nevermind, its not java.

Comment: As I said, I have one million hash keys. Replacing them in a small input text using your method would require one million verifications, each of them iterating over all the characters of the input. The result is a O(nm) algorithm, n the number of characters and m the number of keywords. It's ok for small inputs and small keyword sets, but in my case the performances would be terrible :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Hashes (associative array's) are containers (buckets) of keys. They don't use linear lookups, its direct. In Perl its %hash = (); $hash{'key1'} = 'value'; $somevar = $hash{'key1'}; // $somevar now == 'value'

Comment: In your java example, doesn't java have a replace all method where the replacement is interpolated so the "hashvar[<capture group1 var>]" can be inserted. If not interpolated, then via callback? (Don't know java).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with `NSRegularExpression`:

```
NSString *original = @"Hi {{username}} ... {{foo}}";
NSDictionary *replacementDict = @{@"username": @"Peter", @"foo": @"bar"};

NSString *pattern = @"\\{\\{(.+?)\\}\\}";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                       options:0
                                     error:NULL];

NSMutableString *replaced = [original mutableCopy];
__block NSInteger offset = 0;
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:original
            options:0
              range:NSMakeRange(0, original.length)
             usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange range1 = [result rangeAtIndex:1]; // range of the matched subgroup
    NSString *key = [original substringWithRange:range1];
    NSString *value = replacementDict[key];
    if (value != nil) {
        NSRange range = [result range]; // range of the matched pattern
        // Update location according to previous modifications:
        range.location += offset;
        [replaced replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:value];
        offset += value.length - range.length; // Update offset
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@", replaced);
// Output: Hi Peter ... bar
```

---

A **Swift** version using the [`Regex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex) type that was introduced with Swift 5.7, requires macOS 13+ or iOS 16+):

```swift
import Foundation

let original = "Hi {{username}} ... {{foo}}"
let replacementDict = ["username" : "Peter", "foo" : "bar" ]

var replaced = ""
let regex = /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/
var pos = original.startIndex

// Look for next occurrence of {{key}}.
while let match = try? regex.firstMatch(in: original[pos...]) {
    // Append original text preceding the match.
    replaced += original[pos..<match.range.lowerBound]
    
    // Replace {{key}} by corresponding value and append to the output.
    let key = String(match.1)
    if let value = replacementDict[key] {
        replaced += value
    } else {
        replaced += match.0
    }

    // Continue search after the current match.
    pos = match.range.upperBound
}
// Append original text after the final match.
replaced += original[pos...]

print(replaced)
// Hi Peter ... bar
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I went for the regex 'matchesInString' method combined with a reverse for-loop iterating over all the results backwards. In your solution, are you sure that if multiple keywords are matched, the replacement will be fine? I needed to account for the offset introduced by the first replacement (if it features more or less characters than the associated keyword), hence the backward iteration.

Comment: @AurélienRibon: I am fairly sure that it works correctly now (I had to edit the answer a few times), even with multiple replacements. The `offset` variable takes care of changes in the length.

Comment: This may be years ago but @MartinR , possible to also place a Swift alternative here? This is the closest I found for iOS to having to follow appendReplacement and appendTail in Java.

Comment: @chitgoks: I have added a Swift version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you want directly.

You could look at using [RegexKit Lite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net), specifically the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:usingBlock:` method, where the replacement block holds your logic from your `while` loop above to find and return the appropriate replacement.